# Laravel issue __DIR___

Tags: php, website, dir

> Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in /home/flamore/domains/fans.cal24.pl/public_html/index.php on line 21
>   Warning: require(**DIR**/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/flamore/domains/fans.cal24.pl/public_html/index.php on line 21
>   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '**DIR**/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/flamore/domains/fans.cal24.pl/public_html/index.php on line 21

i'm still a noob at php but i can't get this to work

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: i use PHP 7.1.2

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).